# How to update Angular 2 Reactive form field when changes occurred outside of Angular world

Tags: jquery, angular, angular2-forms, angular2-directives, angular-directive

I recently have started to learn Angular 2 and I am struggling to understand how I should properly connect the changes that occurred in outside world to Angular Reactive Forms.

Specifically, I have an issue with the following example:
I want to create a directive that enhances input with autocomplete functionality that provided by typeahead jQuery plugin. My directive looks like the following:

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[myTypeahead]'
})
class TypeAheadDirective implements AfterViewInit 
{
  constructor(private el: ElementRef) {
  }
  //this will be used as a parameter to source, it is not important for this example
  @Input() myTypeahead: string;
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    let source = new Bloodhound({
      datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('value'),
      queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
      prefetch: 'http://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/data/films/post_1960.json'
    });
    $(this.el.nativeElement).typeahead(null, {source, display: 'value'});
  }
}
```

Then I bind it in an input element in my component like this:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <form (ngSubmit)="save()" [formGroup]="someForm">
      <h2>Hello {{name}}</h2>
      <input formControlName="name" myTypeahead="'http://someRemoteUrl'"/>
    </form>

    <div class="example">Form model: {{someForm.value | json}}</div>
  `,
})
export class App implements OnInit {
  someForm: FormGroup;
  name:string;
  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
    this.name = `Angular! v${VERSION.full}`
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.someForm = this.fb.group({
      name: ''
    });
  }

  save(){

  }
}
```

[Here is a plunker with my example](http://plnkr.co/edit/mIK0soHnbHaYk2MCqgOc?p=preview)

When I start typing something into input - the binding to my `FormGroup` works as expected. But when I pick some hint from autocomplete - it updates input, but doesn't propagate the updated value to my form group.

So my question is if it is possible to signal to a form group about the change that has occurred in the directive?

A possible solution could be to make a component that implements `ControlValueAccessor` to notify about changes, but I want to keep this thing simple with a directive that accepts URL to a data source.

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/LYrkgUfb3BMFOSXRAcHk?p=preview

Comment: @yurzui, thanks for posting this. So it is going to be a directive that works specifically with the reactive form element. I think that it answers my question so I'm willing to accept it when it is posted.

Answer (score 1):

Inside Directive :

You can use `@Output` to send an event and capture it in the form

```
@Output typeaheadResult = new EventEmitter(); 

...

// Whenever user selects a result dispatch the event 
this.typeaheadResult.emit(changedInput);
```

---

Inside your HTML you can capture it

```
 <input formControlName="name"
          myTypeahead="'http://someRemoteUrl'"
          (typeaheadResult)="doSomething()"
           />
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it is an option, but I wanted to omit it because it complicates the usage of the directive, maybe in the case of firing an event outside - it is better to create a component.

Comment: I did not understand, that is how angular officially suggests for events right ?

Comment: I didn't see any official suggestion from angular after searching for my type of situation for about 3 hours, so it is only my opinion. I am just saying that I think that this solution delegates setting the field value to consumer of directive which is not ideal when I need to make a lot of autocompletes throughout the page, therefore it may be better to write a component instead of Output event on directive.

Comment: Ok , I get your point . I guess you already got the solution otherwise we can just check how it's done in NgModel implementation .