# Updating angular reactive form model with values from outside

Tags: javascript, angular

I think i have a very common question about form handling in angular, but don't find any answer for my question after searching and reading for hours.

**The problem:**
I built a reactive form and if the user is in the angular context (typing values etc.), it's all fine. But when i use a chrome plugin like [Web Developer Form Filler](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/web-developer-form-filler/gbagmkohmhcjgbepncmehejaljoclpil?hl=en)
 and fill the form with it, the model doesn't update.

To reproduce the problem, i've created a tiny app here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ltrmpd.

**Form controller:**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  form = new FormGroup({
    name: new FormControl('Valid name', [
      Validators.required,
      Validators.minLength(5)
    ])
  });

  get name() { return this.form.get('name'); }

  onSubmit() {
    // reload all form data and revalidate, but how?

    if (this.form.valid) {
      alert('VALID');
    }
  }
}
```

**Form view:**

```
<form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">

  <div class="form-group row">
    <label for="name" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Name</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input formControlName="name" type="text"class="form-control" id="name" [class.is-invalid]="name.invalid && name.touched" />
      <pre class="invalid-feedback">{{ name.errors | json }}</pre>
    </div>
  </div>

  <pre>{{ form.value | json }}</pre>
  <pre>form.valid: {{ form.valid }}</pre>

  <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="document.getElementById('name').value = 'X'">SET VALUE FROM OUTSIDE</button> model doesn't update <br /><br />

  <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" (click)="name.patchValue('YYY')">SET VALUE ANGULAR WAY</button> updates the model right <br /><br />

  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" [disabled]="!form.valid">Submit</button>
</form>
```

- The default form value is valid
- Click button "SET VALUE FROM OUTSIDE" -> the model doesn't update
- Click "Submit" -> You should not be able to click the button or we update the model and validation state manually after clicking the button

The simplest solution i tried is to update the model and revalidate after the user submits the form. But how can i update the model with the current form values?

I only found this question: [How to update Angular 2 Reactive form field when changes occurred outside of Angular world](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44558732/how-to-update-angular-2-reactive-form-field-when-changes-occurred-outside-of-ang). But i think it's not the same problem, because i don't have any control over this form filler tools.

Comment: How about trigger an `input` event afterward? Does it resolve your problem? Anyway, you must notify Angular that values have been changed if they were changed from outside world. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jybsvy?file=src/app/app.component.html

Comment: It would solve the problem, if i had access to the functions of this tools. The user triggers the "fill form" action with a chrome plugin and it sets the form values according to the example i've posted. It would be safe if i could say "reload data from the form and write it to the model", like i mentioned above.

Answer (score 3):

I was looking for the same event and finally looked into the reactive form implementation under `@angular/core` package then there is an `input` event bind to the form element which is responsible for running validator attached to that form element and updating `FormControlName`.

so to solve your problem you can dispatch an input event on the same form control.

Example -

```
var event = new Event("input");
element.dispatchEvent(event);
```

if you need more insight on the reactive form implementation then you can look for it below.

**Note- Below referring line number of [default_value_accessor.ts](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/f7e9659c4db2624b7aa07442087a38aa88d24fb3/packages/forms/src/directives/default_value_accessor.ts#L68) file.**

In line 68 – we’ve input event bind to the host element which ultimately calling _handleInput

```
host:      {
'(input)': '$any(this)._handleInput($event.target.value)',
'(blur)': 'onTouched()',
'(compositionstart)': '$any(this)._compositionStart()',
'(compositionend)': '$any(this)._compositionEnd($event.target.value)'
},
```

Line 134 – we’ve `_handleInput` definition which is running `onChange` callback which is responsible for running `_executeValidators` function from [validator.ts](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/f7e9659c4db2624b7aa07442087a38aa88d24fb3/packages/forms/src/validators.ts#L386) .

```
/**@internal*/
_handleInput(value: any): void {
   if (!this._compositionMode || (this._compositionMode && !this._composing)) {
      this.onChange(value);
    }
}
```